# Match a pattern, insert the pattern, until next match

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I'm struggling to format a file according to the desired output, using `bash` tools. Here's a sample:

```
address="192.168.1.1"
portid="443"
portid="2000"
address="192.168.1.2"
portid="443"
portid="2000"
```

In essence, what I am trying to achieve is to search for a pattern (in this case, the whole IP address line), and prepend it to each subsequent line until the next match (before the next IP address). The desired output is this:

```
address="192.168.1.1"portid="443"
address="192.168.1.1"portid="2000"
address="192.168.1.2"portid="443"
address="192.168.1.2"portid="2000"
```

How can I achieve this using `grep`, `awk` or `sed`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Considering your actual file is same as shown sample Input_file:

```
awk '/address/{val=$0;next} {print val $0}'  Input_file
```

Comment: This is perfect. Clean and simple. :)

Comment: Thank you :) Glad that it helped you.

Answer (score 3):

**1. sed**

```
sed -n 's/address/&/;Ta;h;d;:a;G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1/;p' file
```

Admittedly, it's more obscure than `awk` or `perl`, which would make more sense here, and whose code is pretty much self-explanatory.

```
s/address/&/;           test (substitute with self) for address
Ta;                     if false, got to label a
h;                      (if true) put the line in the hold buffer
d;                      delete the line from the pattern space
:a;                     set the label a
G;                      append the hold buffer to the pattern space (current line)
s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1/  swap around the newline, so the hold buffer contents
                        are actually prepended to the current line
p                       print the pattern space
```

**Update:** [potong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/967492/potong)'s suggestion is both shorter and easier to follow:

```
sed '/^address/h;//d;G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1/' file
```

**2. awk**

```
awk '/address/{a=$0} /portid/{print a$0}' file
```

**3. perl**

```
perl -lane '$a=$_ if /address/;print $a.$_ if /portid/' file
```

Comment: Perhaps `sed  '/^address/h;//d;G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1/' file` might be a little less busy.

Answer (score 2):

***Input***

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat file
address="192.168.1.1"
portid="443"
portid="2000"
address="192.168.1.2"
portid="443"
portid="2000"
```

***Output***

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ awk '/portid/{print a $0; next}/address/{a=$0}' file
address="192.168.1.1"portid="443"
address="192.168.1.1"portid="2000"
address="192.168.1.2"portid="443"
address="192.168.1.2"portid="2000"
```

Comment: Thanks Akshay, this certainly looks spot on! Saved my day! :)

Comment: You should accept an answer at some point... it is the polite thing to do.  And I also think it should be an `awk` solution.  Makes sense here.

Comment: Sorry Steve I am new here and didn't know I have to do so. Have just done that, thanks for this. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sed answer.  Have to use the hold space carefully.

**`sed -n -e '/addr/h;/portid/{x;G;s/\nportid/portid/;p;s/portid.*//;h;}'`**

Explanation:

- `sed -n` - only print when explicitly told to print
- `/addr/h` - save the addr lines in the hold space
- `/portid/{...}` - on each line matching portid, do this:

  - `x` get the addr line from the hold space, put the portid line in the hold space instead
  - `G` append the portid line to the addr line
  - `s/\nportid/portid/` - remove the line break at the start of portid line
  - `p` print the combined lines
  - `s/portid.*//` strip the portid stuff back off the combined line
  - `h` save the addr line in the hold space again
- Of course if the input is really this simple, you can condense the places where I used `addr` or `portid` to just `a` and `p` but `sed` is arcane enough.

Output:

```
$ sed -n -e '/addr/h;/portid/{x;G;s/\nportid/portid/;p;s/portid.*//;h}' addr.txt 
address="192.168.1.1"portid="443"
address="192.168.1.1"portid="2000"
address="192.168.1.2"portid="443"
address="192.168.1.2"portid="2000"
```